# Declaring class pointer variable outside class

Tags: c++, class, oop, scope

So let's say we have following structures in *header* file:

```
struct x {
    struct y {
        int a;
        y* b;
        y(int _a, y* _b) {
            a = _a;
            b = _b;
        }
    };   
    void z() {
        y* c = NULL;
    }
};
```

We also have *main* file which looks like this:

```
void f() {
    //place for new pointer from question below
}

int main() {
    ...
}
```

Is there a possibility to declare new **y** type pointer in **f** that would work for **f** the same **c** pointer works for **z** (pointer can operate on **y** type and can't be used outside the function)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type `y` is nested inside `x`, so to access it from outside you will have to prefix it with `x` and the scope resolution operator `::`.

```
void f() {
   x::y* c = nullptr;
}
```

should work.